# C# Mysql connection working only on localhost

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm connecting to a mysql database in c#, and it all works well as long as I input the server address as "localhost" or its ip, but if I try a remote ip it fails with:

```
Error: 0 : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

here's the code:

```
server = Properties.Settings.Default.DBHost;
port = Properties.Settings.Default.DBPort;
database = Properties.Settings.Default.DBName ;
uid = Properties.Settings.Default.DBUser;
password = Properties.Settings.Default.DBPassword ;

string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "PORT=" + port + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

[...]

if (this.OpenConnection() == true){
    // exec db operations
}
else{
    MessageBox.Show("Database Connection Error.");
}
```

Tested:

- No firewall restrictions
- Same error in different computers
- Already tried on with different remote databases, all with set privileges and accessible from other sources

Comment: Does the remote host allow non localhost connections? The default configuration of MySQL might not allow connections from other hosts for security reasons.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i already access the same db from multiple instances (php, android app...) so non localhost connections are allowed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its your mysql server then,

- Check you port is open or not. (probably 3306)
- Change your bind-address in your my.ini file (from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0)
- Double check the user your trying to connect to server has necessary privileges

If its not your mysql server then,

- Ask the provider whether they are supporting remote connections or not.

Comment: Thanks, I tried connecting to a mysql server in another machine (same lan) and to a remote server, the port is 3306 and both are already in use so they're accessible and the user has all necessary privileges. Very strange...

Comment: You were right on the second point, I forgot to edit bind-address! It didn't occur to me that every other access to the db (android-app and web-app) was made via php scripts that returned the requested data in json, so I had no problems. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1st you have to check if your server is supporting remote `MySQL database Connection` then

You can try this `MySQL Connection String Builder` example, i'm working with all the time .. no errors :

```
_connectionStr = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Server = "127.0.0.1",
                Database = myDatabase,
                UserID = myUserName,
                Password = myPassword,
                ConnectionTimeout=60,
                Port = 3306,
                AllowZeroDateTime = true
            };
            _con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionStr.ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                _con.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error, help i can't get connected!");
            }
```

Hope this works!

Comment: The problem resided elsewhere, but this way of building a connection is far more detailed and elgant than mine, so I will start using it. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your MySQL Server is not configured to listen to any of your IP Interface.
Maybe it is just listening into your "localhost:3306"

Check it in your MySQL Server config file "bind-address".